# How to customize symfony2 forms upon retrieval?

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I have a case where we create registration for sports events.

The registration contains some fields specific to each sport. Some of which will be named similarly although they will be different for each sport. Example: "favorite position on the field":

For Basketball it would be a choice field between:

- Point guard
- Shooting guard
- etc...

For baseball, it would be the same choice field but with some different choices available:

- Pitcher
- Infield
- Outfield
- ...

When first creating the form (for display), the sport is passed as part of the data in the registration:

```
$registration = new Registration;
$registration->setEvent($event);
```

and `$event->getSport();` would return the sport for that event.

So far so good, and adding a listener to the generation of my form, I can set only the fields specific to that sport:

```
public static function getSubscribedEvents()
{
    return [FormEvents::POST_SET_DATA => 'preSetData'];
}

/**
 * @param event DataEvent
 */
public function preSetData(DataEvent $event)
{
    $form = $event->getForm();

    if (null === $event->getData()) {
        return;
    }

    // (The get event here means the real life sports gathering)
    $sport = $event->getData()->getEvent()->getSport();
    /**
     * Then I customize the fields depending on the current sport
     */
}
```

The problem comes when the user submits this form back. In this case, `$event->getData()->getEvent()` is `null`.

The "event" (real life one) is a `document_id` field in the registration form (using MongoDB here).

If I listen to the `::BIND` event instead of `::PRE_SET_DATA`, then I can access everything, but it's too late to customize the form as it is already bound. `::PRE_BIND` does the same as `::PRE_SET_DATA`.

How can I correctly retrieve my Event and Sport Documents here in order to customize my form and validate it appropriately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So ... Finally found how to do this properly.It requires subscribing to two different events.

First time the form is built, some data is passed to it, therefore, the `PRE_SET_DATA` event contains that data and everything works fine as explained in the question.

On the moment the form is submitted, it is first created with NO data, therefore the data accessed in `PRE_SET_DATA` will be null. In this case we skip over the form customization:

```
public function preSetData(DataEvent $event)
{
    $myEvent = $event->getData()->getEvent();

    if (null === $myEvent) {
        return;
    }

    $this->customizeForm();
}
```

This ensures that we don't run into issues when submitting the form and no data is passed, however `getData()` will return an empty object and not NULL.

Now, when the form is submitted, we will bind it to the data received. That's when we want to interfere. So we'll also subscribe to the `PRE_BIND` event:

```
public static function getSubscribedEvents()
{
    return [
        FormEvents::PRE_BIND => 'preBind',
        FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA => 'preSetData',
    ];
}
```

In pre-bind, the data we receive is only an array of values and not an object graph.
But if we injected the object manager in our listener, then we can find our objects and work with them:

```
public function preBind(DataEvent $event)
{
    $data = $event->getData();
    $id = $data['event'];
    $myEvent = $this->om
                ->getRepository('Acme\DemoBundle\Document\Event')
                ->find(new \MongoId($id));
    if($myEvent === null){
        $msg = 'The event %s could not be found';
        throw new \Exception(sprintf($msg, $id));
    }

    $this->customizeForm();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why would you need an event to do such task? You can define the fields in the `buildForm()` action of the form class. To access the event object simply use `$options['data']->getEvent()`

Comment: The `buildForm` method is used to define the FormType, but not each entity of this type. So if I were to use many instances of that form, they would not be configured differently (no matter what data is passed), if customizing things in the `buildForm` method.

Comment: Well, the form is created on the "build" phase. To reuse this kind of functionality you can create embedded form "SportEventFormType" and pass the $sport object there.